# Wi-Fi is not a recognized network service in macOS 13.0.1

Tags: macos-ventura

I have come across an issue that is usually easily worked around but for some reason I cannot get around it here in macOS 13.0.1.

% sudo networksetup -listallnetworkservices
An asterisk (*) denotes that a network service is disabled.
Wi-Fi
Thunderbolt Bridge

sudo networksetup -getinfo 'Wi-Fi'
Wi-Fi is not a recognized network service.
** Error: The parameters were not valid.

And it is wrok in other macOS(less than macOS 13.0.1), Not sure what I am doing wrong, Any help is appreciated.

And it is wrok in other macOS(less than macOS 13.0.1), I am not sure it is a bug in macOS 13.0.1